# Birt - Report Engine Command Line (genReport.sh) not outputting anything

Tags: birt

\Hi all,

I just installed version 3.7 and here's what I'm trying to run.  It runs for about 30 seconds and doesn't show any errors. The problem is I can't find test.pdf anywhere.

```
export BIRT_HOME=/opt/local/birt-runtime-3_7_2
cd $BIRT_HOME/ReportEngine/
./genReport.sh runrender -f PDF -o /tmp/test.pdf /opt/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.26/webapps/Birt/user_reports/scientific_services.rptdesign
```

I also tried running this as the root user with the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the "-m" (or --mode) flag before "runrender":

```
./genReport.sh -m runrender -f PDF -o /tmp/test.pdf /opt/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.26/webapps/Birt/user_reports/scientific_services.rptdesign
```

Comment: Hey that works, thanks!  Wow $500 because I didn't read the help closely :-(  I hope I learned my lesson.

Comment: It's making me wait 19 hours before I can award the 500 dollars but you'll get it I think unless someone posts something amazing I guess.

Comment: Oh, I guess they're just points, not dollars.  Now I'm not so sad.